# Angular 6 Search FrontEnd Implementation from Observable subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, full-text-search, frontend

due to a given API which I need to use, I need to implement a full text search in FrontEnd.
THe problem is following, on startup the frontend gets all data entries from BackEnd and subscribes them inside a component(using async pipe). So there is no API call support which can call BackEnd with a method like getById().

I need to implement this search ability completely in FrontEnd.

So given an object with some property:

```
export interface SomeObject {
  name: string
  // some properties
}
```

the template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
 <!-- show data entries -->
</tr>
```

the component:

```
data: Observable<SomeObject[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  // makes API call to get all data entries
  this.data = this.dataService.fetchData()
}
```

My question: Do you know any good example implentations or a good package how to implement a full search ability in FrontEnd being completely independent from BackEnd without making API calls?

All solutions I can find are using a function like getById() to call BackEnd. This is what I cannot use because I can't change the given BackEnd.
If the pipe or package supports autocomplete would be really nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localvariable

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data | async;let data">
    <tr *ngFor="let s of data | pipe">
     <!-- show data entries -->
    </tr>
 </ng-container>
```

Then create filter pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, searchValue: any): any {
    console.log(value, searchValue);
    if (!searchValue) {
      return value;
    }
    else {
      return value.filter(value => {
        return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    }

  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxukhg

Comment: Thanks, I already found a nice solution from this [link](https://www.code-sample.com/2018/07/angular-6-search-filter-pipe-table-by.html)

Also i don't get this part of code from the link `filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));`

Comment: I'll try your solution later :) and send some feedback

Comment: your solution works too, but using RegEx like in my link for matching results is a bit more powerful :)